# How can I access this list in another class?

Tags: java, list

I have created a list of items from a CSV file, but am not sure how to access this list in another class. I have created the instance of the list class in the new class, but have not been able to find a way to access the list.

```
public class ListClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader();
        List list = csvReader.Read("csvFile.csv");
    }
}
```

I have been able to print the list, and so I know that it's definitely working, but I'm just not sure how I'd access it in another class. The new class is currently empty, aside from the following;

```
ListClass listClass = new ListClass();
```

Comment: Have you made sure that both files are in the same package?

Comment: Did you import `ListClass` in your other class? Did you build with all relevant class files on the classpath? And when you mean *access*, do you mean *initialize*, *instantiate*, or *actually use the values*?

Comment: The list you are trying to access is only accessible from the main method. Try to assign the list to a class variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 )Add your list as a Field of ListClass and put your initialization inside the constructor.

```
public class ListClass {
 public List list;
 ListClass(){
   try{
        CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader();
        list = csvReader.Read("csvFile.csv");
       }catch(IOException e){
         //handle the exception
       }
   }
}
```

2) create an object of ListClass in OtherClass.

```
public class OtherClass{
  public static void main(String[] args){
  ListClass listClass = new ListClass();
  List newList = listClass.list;// your list
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this has genuinely helped me

Answer (score 2):

You should store the list as a private instance variable in your ListClass and create a getter for it:

```
public class ListClass {
    private List list = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
        new ListClass();
      } catch(IOException ioEx){
        // error handling
      }
    }

    public ListClass() throws IOException {
      CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader();
      list = csvReader.Read("csvFile.csv");
    }

    public List getList(){
      return list;
    }
}
```

Then you can access it from your other class:

```
try {
  ListClass listClass = new ListClass();
  List list = listClass.getList();
} catch(IOException ioEx){
  // error handling
}
```

Comment: You might want to make the field private, otherwise having a getter is a bit of an overhead.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the list accessible to other classes by doing one of the following:

1. Delcare the list as a class level variable and make it public

```
class ListClass {
  public List csvList;

  ...
}
```

2. Declare the list as a private class variable and have an accessor

```
class ListClass {
  private List csvList;

  public List getCsvList() {
    return this.csvList;
  }

  ...
}
```

There are a lot of other ways to access a class variable. The second one is a very common way of doing it.